# I am working on geojson file with 10000 features now in order to plot heatmaps I need to modify all 10000 features any efficient way to do this?

Tags: json, geojson

I tired all the options available csv to geojson, but all are suitable for limited no of features only.

I am plotting heatmaps based on the CDR value so I need to change the color properties of each feature based on cdr values for 10000 features..

```
               {
               "type": "FeatureCollection",
               "features": [
               {
               "geometry": {
               "type": "Polygon",
               "coordinates": [
              [
              [
              9.0114910478323,
              45.35880131440966
              ],
              [
              9.014491488013135,
              45.35880097314403
              ],
              [
              9.0144909480813,
              45.35668565341486
              ],
              [
              9.011490619692509,
              45.356685994655464
              ],
              [
              9.0114910478323,
              45.35880131440966
              ]
              ]
              ]
              },
              "type": "Feature",
              "id": 0,
              "properties": {
              "stroke": "#80ff80",
              "stroke-width": 4,
              "stroke-opacity": 1,
              "fill": "#ff0000",
              "fill-opacity": 1,
              "cellId": 1,
              "Call-In Volume": 1000,
              "Call-Out Volume": 1000,
              "SMS-Sent Volume": 1000,
              "SMS-Received Volume": 1000,
              "Data Volume": 500
              }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no other efficient way than taking each feature and modifying fill for that feature based on CDR value.